# Install specific version of package with tlmgr

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

I was wondering if it's possible to specify the version of a package to install.

In the texlive.tlpdb file or when using `tlmgr info <package-name>`, there is a revision number which I understand to be some sort of versioning. Can I somehow specify the version I want to install when using `tlmgr install`? If not, can I somehow manually do it?

Comment: Which package are you thinking about? Some packages support loading different versions via `\usepackage{<package>}[version]`. In the bigger picture, packages don't exist on their own, they often rely on features or the latex kernel or other packages. If you need a specific version of a package, it might make sense to have the whole ecosystem to match this version.

Comment: You can find docker images of specific timestamps at https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive

Comment: Normally it is not a good idea to mix packages from varying dates. But there are daily snapshots of texlive. I don't know if you can use them to install a single package but you could try `tlmgr install --repo https://texlive.info/tlnet-archive/2023/02/03/tlnet/ package`